# empty dropdown in JSP

Tags: jsp

I'm trying to load a list of cars from mysql database.  But my dropdown list is coming up empty.  My code is below.

```
<select>
<c:forEach var="line" items="${cars}">
    <option><c:out value="${line}"/></option>
</c:forEach>
</select>

<%
ArrayList<CarsDataBean> cars = CarsDAO.getCars();
request.setAttribute("cars", cars.getCars());
%>
```

Comment: Are you certain that your getting is actually returning any data?

Comment: Yes, the DAO is working correctly.  getCars() brings back 4 attributes one of which is carName.  Which is the value I'm trying to populate.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the attribute before you use it. Here is demonstration code.

```
<%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<c:set value="Ford,Chevy,Honda" var="vehicles" scope="request"/>
The cars in the list are ${cars}.
<%
    request.setAttribute("cars", request.getAttribute("vehicles"));
%>
The cars in the list are ${cars}.
```

Output:
The cars in the list are . The cars in the list are Ford,Chevy,Honda.